# How to use fread() as readLines() without auto column detection?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a 5Gb .dat file (> 10million lines). The format of each line is like `aaaa bb cccc0123 xxx kkkkkkkkkkkkkk` or `aaaaabbbcccc01234xxxkkkkkkkkkkkkkk` for example. Because `readLines` has poor performance while reading big file, I choose `fread()` to read this, but error was occurred:

```
library("data.table")
x <- fread("test.DAT")
Error in fread("test.DAT") : 
  Expecting 5 cols, but line 5 contains text after processing all cols. It is very likely that this is due to one or more fields having embedded sep=' ' and/or (unescaped) '\n' characters within unbalanced unescaped quotes. fread cannot handle such ambiguous cases and those lines may not have been read in as expected. Please read the section on quotes in ?fread.
In addition: Warning message:
In fread("test.DAT") :
  Unable to find 5 lines with expected number of columns (+ middle)
```

How to use `fread()` as `readLines()` without auto column detecting? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a trick.  You could use a `sep` value that you know is not in the file.  Doing that forces `fread()` to read the whole line as a single column.  Then we can drop that column to an atomic vector (shown as `[[1L]]` below). Here's an example on a csv where I use `?` as the `sep`.  This way it acts similar to `readLines()`, only a lot faster.

```
f <- fread("Batting.csv", sep= "?", header = FALSE)[[1L]]
head(f)
# [1] "playerID,yearID,stint,teamID,lgID,G,AB,R,H,2B,3B,HR,RBI,SB,CS,BB,SO,IBB,HBP,SH,SF,GIDP"
# [2] "abercda01,1871,1,TRO,NA,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,"       
# [3] "addybo01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,118,30,32,6,0,0,13,8,1,4,0,,,,,"  
# [4] "allisar01,1871,1,CL1,NA,29,137,28,40,4,5,0,19,3,1,2,5,,,,," 
# [5] "allisdo01,1871,1,WS3,NA,27,133,28,44,10,2,2,27,1,1,0,2,,,,,"
# [6] "ansonca01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,120,29,39,11,3,0,16,6,2,2,1,,,,,"
```

Other uncommon characters you can try in `sep` are `\ ^ @ # =` and others.  We can see that this will produce the same output as `readLines()`.  It's just a matter of finding a `sep` value that is not present in the file.

```
head(readLines("Batting.csv"))
# [1] "playerID,yearID,stint,teamID,lgID,G,AB,R,H,2B,3B,HR,RBI,SB,CS,BB,SO,IBB,HBP,SH,SF,GIDP"
# [2] "abercda01,1871,1,TRO,NA,1,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,,,,"                                  
# [3] "addybo01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,118,30,32,6,0,0,13,8,1,4,0,,,,,"                             
# [4] "allisar01,1871,1,CL1,NA,29,137,28,40,4,5,0,19,3,1,2,5,,,,,"                            
# [5] "allisdo01,1871,1,WS3,NA,27,133,28,44,10,2,2,27,1,1,0,2,,,,,"                           
# [6] "ansonca01,1871,1,RC1,NA,25,120,29,39,11,3,0,16,6,2,2,1,,,,,"
```

**Note:** As @Cath has mentioned in the comments, you could also simply use the line break character `\n` as the `sep` value.

Comment: This should be heavily upvoted. Nice trick, actually worked with sep='~' in my case.

Comment: why not `sep="\n"`?

Comment: @Cath - Yes, I guess that can be used as well.

Comment: I know this thread is old - but what do I now do with the rows? Whats an efficient way to get the rows into a data.table?

Comment: @lukehawk - If you have the character vector like above, you can do `fread(paste(f, collapse = "\n"))`.  Otherwise I would just use `fread` to read straight from the file.

Comment: @lukehawk the `fread(paste(f, collapse = "\n"))` takes a very long time to execute even on a less than 100,000 object size.