# data.table fails to read mixed lines from a file, some quoted and some unquoted

Tags: r, data.table

I have a file that contains SQL log, a small section of which is attached [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/knr0slw4dzfdlr0/test.txt?dl=0)

`data.table::fread` fails to read test.txt and spurts out this error:

```
Error in fread("test.txt") : 
  Expected sep ('   ') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 0 when detecting types from point 0: "2017-10-28T06:44:52.057649Z   417 Query select term.class_session_id from class_sessions as term inner join tbl_auth as user on term.teacher_id = user.user_id where term.ends_on < now() and term.session_state=1 and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(term.ends_on,now())+0) < 3600 order by term.starts_on desc"
In addition: Warning message:
In fread("test.txt") :
  Starting data input on line 2 and discarding line 1 because it has too few or too many items to be column names or data: "2017-10-28T06:44:52.054789Z   417 Query insert into event_log(service_name,user_id,UUID,xml_input,request_time) values('GetMyTodaysSessions','616','0','<Sunstone><Action><Service>GetMyTodaysSessions</Service><UserId>616</UserId></Action></Sunstone>','2017-10-28 12:14:52')"
```

I understand that few of the lines are not enclosed in quotes (" ").

How can we read a file that has 4 columns (tab separated) but some lines are with quotes and some without? Is that a problem?

I could understand that `fread` is intelligent to read around the quotes, and actually ignore the quotes but it seems to fail if unquoted text is encountered between quoted text.

I am trying to get rid of the unquoted rows in the log file, but the error in fread makes me think that the absence of quotes is not the problem - it could be something else.

Can someone examine the test.txt and see how it can be read in?

Comment: Testing on the dev version of data.table (albeit from September), it works fine for me. `fread("test.txt", header=FALSE)`...

Comment: Testing on version `1.10.0` (not the latest), this works for me: `data.table::fread("https://www.dropbox.com/s/knr0slw4dzfdlr0/test.txt?dl=1", header = FALSE, quote = "") `, though leaves "parasite" double quotes in first and last fields

Comment: Strangely I can't copy paste the code you typed @Aurèle. The dropbox link even if copied from my link does not work with fread (I have 1.10.4 version of data.table). But the text is readable from the file if it is local. I will test with some real data and post a more relevant file.

Comment: I replaced the end of the URL with `dl=1`

Comment: I need to modify to a more general question and close this one. Shall I close or modify the same question? My more general question will include a link to a 100,000 rows SQL log file and will show how fread gets stuck at various elements. I got a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920031/how-to-use-fread-as-readlines-without-auto-column-detection) but this solution is not feasible if you have dozens of such rows and every time you exclude one element of the atomic vector and pass the vector through fread you get blocked at another.