# Efficient way to Remove certain lines in a text file and then convert to table using fread()

Tags: r, utf-8, fread

I have a data file like the format shown below. There are 5 columns and some 2000000 rows

```
# some text
# some more text
#
#       Column names                                            Units                         
#       ------------------------------------------------------  ------------------------ 
#@   1  "aaaa"                                                  "s"                       
#@   2  "bbbbbbb "                                              "kg"                     
#@   3  "cccccccc"                                              "m"                     
#@   4  "dddddddd"                                              "lb"                     
#@   5  "eeeeeeee"                                              "m"                     

2 4 5 6 7 
7 8 9 3 2 
...
...
...

# row 145800
# row 145801
# row 145802 
# row 145803
# row 145804

3 4 6 7 9
```

The idea is to create a dataframe using fread(). Before that,
I need to skip rows that contain the "#" character. One issue in this example is that the "#" is also present somewhere in the middle
of the text file, as in rows 145800 to 145804. So I split the data into two different character vectors and then merging them to to remove the "#" in rows 145800 to 145804. The reason to retain the lines with "#@" is for the column names. I will remove them later after mapping them to columns

```
# pathof data file 
path <-  "C:/data.txt"

# read original data file. 
# Does the same as readLines() - inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920031/how-to-use-fread-as-readlines-without-auto-column-detection
lines_original <- fread(path, sep= "?", header = FALSE)[[1L]] 

# Read the first 100 lines of the file into a character vector
lines_subset<- fread(path, sep= "?", header = FALSE, nrows = 100)[[1L]]


# Identify the lines that contain the special character in the first 100 lines
special_lines_1 <- grep("\\#", lines_subset)

# Identify the lines that contain the special character in the entire file
special_lines_2 <- grep("\\#", lines_original)


# Subset of lines_subset containing "#" 
lines_1 <- lines_subset[special_lines_1] 


# Subset of lines_original  containing "#" 

lines_2 <- lines_original[-special_lines_2]

# merging lines_1 and lines_2 so that "#" is removed everywhere apart from first 100 lines 
lines_new <- c(lines_1, lines_2)


skip <- tail(grep("\\#", readLines(textConnection(lines_new))),1)
```

I now want to convert  the lines_new into a dataframe using the below code

```
df <- fread(text = lines_new, skip = skip,  header = FALSE)
```

As you can see, I use the fread() call multiple times, is there a way to avoid using the fread() at the end, since the data is already imported in the memory?

Comment: It's hard to help without having the file or at least its lines 145800-145804.

Comment: @AndreyShabalin Actually, I looked at the data closely (it took a while to open in windows)  and somehow, there is the special character embedded in those lines. Is there a way to remove those lines from the text file?

Comment: How about `readLines(path, n=38)`?

Comment: @AndreWildberg I want the program to find out n. So I used skip <- tail(grep("\\#", readLines(path)),1) that should give 38. But I have these lines 145800 - 148804 where somehow the special character was introduced. So I want to remove those lines in the text files -something like grep("\\#", readLines(p_header where n>100))

Comment: If you know you want the first 100 lines max anyways why not read those in and filter with grep afterwards? This way avoids reading in the file twice.

Comment: @Dave2e I edited the question and also added an example file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this approach.

1. Load the text file as string,
2. Remove lines with '#' prefix. I use regex,
3. Use fread to convert to table.

This is the code:

```
readLines('tes.txt') %>% 
  grep('^[^\\#]', ., value = T) %>% 
  fread(text = .)
```